# Using Python 3 in virtualenv not working properly

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

python 3.5.2 run cmd ( virtualenv -p python3 venv)

Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /var/www/html/python3_virtualenv/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /var/www/html/python3_virtualenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...

stay of execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed correctly pip on your computer to install virtualenvwrapper ? :

```
py -m pip install 
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

When you have pip :

```
py -m pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

To start your virtualenv correctly :

```
py -m venv /path/vers/projet/myproject
```

To go on your project before using command :

```
workon myproject
```

To install any other package you need :

```
py -m pip install any_other_name_of_the_package_you_need
```

set myproject for the name of your project, and set /path/vers/projet/myproject for the location on your project.

Don't forget to activate.bat your project too.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use this command instead of virtualenv

```
pyvenv<virtualenv name>
```

You can use pyvenv default wrapper for python versions3